# Rule in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, rules

I need to put a rule in a table's column.

Is a date's column. And i need a rule that only accepts an update only if the day is saturday or sunday. And between march to november.

I'm doing this, but doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK check_name ( (datepart(dw, myDate) =7 OR (datepart(dw, myDate) = 1)) AND (datepart(mm, myDate) < 2 AND datepart(mm, myDate) < 12 ) )
```

What's wrong with this?
Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't be  (datepart(mm, myDate) **>** 2?

Comment: Yes sorry, i writed it wrong. But even with ">2" y get an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'.

Comment: `CHECK` keyword must be placed *after* constraint name `check_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT  check_name  CHECK 
   ( (datepart(dw, myDate) = 7 OR (datepart(dw, myDate) = 1)) AND 
      (MONTH(myDate) BETWEEN 3 AND 11) )
```